# I can't send limit order when connected to FTX

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I've created a small script that should send entry limit orders to FTX.
I just need the script to send the limit orders for the entry, I will close the positions manually.

While I'm connected to FTX via the Tradingview panel everything works fine, except that it doen't insert any limit order.

Here the Code:

```
//@version=5
strategy(title=" PERPETUAL STRATEGY)", overlay=true, shorttitle="Perpetual", default_qty_value = 0.001)
import TradingView/Strategy/3

//Get Current Price
Current_Price = request.security(syminfo.ticker, "1", close)

//Input 
distance_form_price = input.float(defval =0.6, step=0.1, title = "Distant from price") / 100


// Create SMA levels

periods = input.int(title = "Periods", defval = 4)
sma_buy = ta.sma((Current_Price * (1 - distance_form_price)), periods)
sma_sell = ta.sma((Current_Price * (1 + distance_form_price)), periods)

Buy_Limit= true
Sell_Limit= true

// Entry Strategy
if Buy_Limit
    strategy.order("Buy (Limit)", strategy.long, limit = sma_buy)

if Sell_Limit
    strategy.entry("Sell (Limit)", strategy.short, limit = sma_sell)

// Get Limit Price Line

plot(sma_buy, title = "long", color = color.aqua)
plot(sma_sell, title = "short", color = color.lime)
```

I've looked into the official documentation but no luck.

I've also tried strategy.entry, but the result doesn't change.
The FTX account has the required liquidity for the operations.

Can anybody help?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

A pine script cannot trade automatically for you natively.

You'll have to forward the TradingView alerts to a software connected to FTX to automate your trading.

2/ The limit parameter from the strategy.order function is to be understood as a take profit parameter, not as a limit entry price parameter

3/ The Pine engine doesn't allow to set a different fee for market vs limit orders, so you can using strategy.order has no benefits imo versus using strategy.entry and strategy.exit

4/ To simulate the limit entry orders, you could do something like this

```
sma_buy = ta.sma((Current_Price * (1 - distance_form_price)), periods)
sma_sell = ta.sma((Current_Price * (1 + distance_form_price)), periods)

Buy_Limit= true
Sell_Limit= true

// Entry Strategy
if close >= sma_buy
    strategy.order("Buy (Limit)", strategy.long)

if close <= sma_sell
    strategy.entry("Sell (Limit)", strategy.short)
```

Comment: As for for forward TradingView alerts to a software connected to FTX, do you have any raccomandation? Thank you very much againg

Comment: You can use Profitview or alertatron or tradingview.to or autoview